# How can I use regex in python to find words between tags?

Tags: python, regex

i have two string variables.

```
var1 = "<tag> variable number one </tag>"
var2 = "<tag> variable
 number 
 two </tag>"
```

Second variable have new lines.
This code is working for var1 but not working for second because it has new lines. I need get text "variable number two"

```
print(re.findall(r'(<TEXT>.+?</TEXT>)', var2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `re.findall` in dot all mode:

```
var2 = """<tag> variable
number 
two </tag>"""

matches = re.findall(r'<tag>(.+?)</tag>', var2, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
[' variable\nnumber \ntwo ']
```

By the way, if you expect things like nested tags or other nested content, you should consider learning how to work with Python's Beautiful Soup library, which is more geared towards parsing HTML than regular expressions.  That is, in general you should *not* use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: thank you very match. 6 min  for accept answer.

Comment: I am not working with html tags. These tags are needed to simplify text processing.